extent spark report.html generated is not interactive
This is my code:
@Before
public void beforeScenario() throws IOException {
    // Start a new test         
    ExtentSparkReporter spark= new ExtentSparkReporter("target/SparkReport.html");
    extent = new ExtentReports();
    final File CONF = new File("src/test/resources/configs/report_gui_files/spark-config.xml");
    //spark.config().setCss("src/test/resources/configs/report_gui_files/spark-style.css");
    spark.loadXMLConfig(CONF);
    spark.config().setDocumentTitle("IDRS Auotmation Framework ");
    // Name of the report
    spark.config().setReportName("SAS VI Auomtation");
    // Dark Theme
    spark.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
    extent.attachReporter(spark);
 }

@After
public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {
    // Capture screenshot on failure
    ExtentTest test = scenarioMap.get(scenario.getName());
    if (scenario != null && scenario.isFailed()) {
         test.fail("Scenario Failed");
        captureScreenshot(scenario);
    } else {
        test.pass("Scenario Passed");
    }
    extent.flush();
}

I get an un interactive html output as below:
enter image description here
I added a folder with report gui files to support the reports with js, css and spark-config.xml. enter image description here
Its all not working to get an interactive output. I get a html displayed with text and bullets instead of navigation, tabs and dropdowns. Please can anyone suggest ?
I tried placing report gui folder with all necessary files. Tried to change the spark.html with text editor to append js source. Tried changing paths. Nothing is working
